# Understand how reified and wildcards work in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm sorry if the title of the question is not really significant, but I haven't found a better way to describe this problem.

I'm writing some Kotlin extension methods for Hadoop, and yesterday I encounted a strange error that I don't understand. I wrote a couple of extension methods like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : InputFormat<*, *>, reified K : Mapper<*, *, *, *>> Job.addMultipleInputPath(path: Path) {
  MultipleInputs.addInputPath(this, path, T::class.java, K::class.java)
}

inline fun <reified T : OutputFormat<*, *>, reified Key : Any, reified Value : Any> Job.addMultipleNamedOutput(namedOutput: String) {
  MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(this, namedOutput, T::class.java, Key::class.java, Value::class.java)
}

inline fun <reified T : Mapper<*, *, KeyClass, ValueClass>, reified KeyClass : Any, reified ValueClass : Any> Job.setMapper() {
  this.setMapperClass<T>()
  this.mapOutput<KeyClass, ValueClass>()
}
```

An if I try to call them in my Driver class, (1) and (3) work but (2) gives me a compile error:

```
with(Job.getInstance()) {
  // works
  addMultipleInputPath<TextInputFormat, SensorsMapperType2>(secInput)

  // 2 type arguments expected for class TextOutputFormat<K: Any!, V: Any!> : FileOutputFormat<K!, V!> 
  // defined in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output
  addMultipleNamedOutput<TextOutputFormat, Text, SensorData>(HIGH_TEMP)

  // works
  setMapper<NGramMapper, Text, IntWritable>()
}
```

If I correct the call using `<TextOutputFormat<Any, Any>>` everything works fine, but I don't understand why this happens. Is there something that I'm missing on how reified and generics work in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about raw types, which kotlin doesn't allow.

This format works:

```
addMultipleNamedOutput<TextOutputFormat<Text, SensorData>, Text, SensorData>(HIGH_TEMP) //(1)
```

These two don't:

```
addMultipleNamedOutput<TextOutputFormat, Text, SensorData>(HIGH_TEMP) //(2)
```

So things get clear now. `TextOutputFormat` is illegal because Kotlin doesn't allow raw types. You have to specify the type arguments, which is missing in (2). Adding them result in format (1).

This looks a bit verbose, but there is currently no workaround (at least IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but how should I change the signature of `Job.addMultipleNamedOutput` in order to make possible (1)? Because for now it accepts only (2), while for (1) it complains for the missing Key and Value.

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake. I'm terribly sorry for that.